# VBA Excel: How to assign range of cells to another range of cells?

Tags: vba, excel

New Excel VBA user here. I feel like I made a silly syntax mistake.

I am trying to copy some vertical cells in one worksheet, to horizontal cells in another worksheet.

```
Worksheets("Master").Range("D14:F14").Value = Worksheets("Temp").Range("B12:B14").Value
```

However, the above command seems to only paste the value of B12 to cells D14:F14. Is there a way to paste the cells of B12, B13, and B14 to D14:F14?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Application.Transpose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196261.aspx):

```
Worksheets("Master").Range("D14:F14").Value = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Temp").Range("B12:B14").Value)
```

Or [PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx):

```
Worksheets("Temp").Range("B12:B14").Copy
Worksheets("Master").Range("D14").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, , , True
```

If you only want values then the first is best.  When transposing with `PasteSpecial` one must use the `xlPasteAll`.  It will throw an error if one tries to paste values only with transpose as true.